# PowerShell invoke-webrequest works in ISE but not in cmd

Tags: powershell

I have a little prompt, that works in ISE, but I have to execute it in an external scheduler, that only can handle windows batch.

**invoke-webrequest "https://www.ecb.europa.eu//stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-hist-90d.xml" -outfile #path#**

Trying to execute it in cmd (with powershell.exe in front) throws the error:
"invoke-webrequest : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send."

Same Error with "[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12" before the command.

The strange thing for me is, that it works on other machines, so it must be a setting in the CMD.

Comment: Show us your code when using _"Trying to execute it in cmd (with powershell.exe in front)"_

Comment: What happens when you try [`PowerShell.exe -NoExit ...`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)?

Comment: If I do `powershell.exe "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-hist-90d.xml' -OutFile 'D:\Test\rates.xml'"` it works without any problem..

Comment: I am always getting the following error.

Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS
secure channel.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eur ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

Comment: @init5 that certainly looks like an SSL error, but it's different than the error in your question? Try it again, forcing tls12: `powershell.exe "[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-hist-90d.xml' -OutFile 'D:\Test\rates.xml'"`

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Same error, but the funny thing is still that it works on another server. Is there a setting or a special module necessary that happens to be already installed on the other server?

Comment: Not really - TLS settings like ciphers are mostly determined by the OS schannel settings. If you log into that server interactively, start powershell, and run the `nvoke-WebRequest`,

Comment: (oops) command, does it succeed? What about just opening the url in internet explorer on the server? Some other factors like system time being way off or corporate security stuff can cause problems too. There's not much in powershell/cmd specifically that would give you this error though